# Condetional break inside the For loop and continue execution

Tags: vb.net

How can i break the loop and continue execution from the next line comes after the loop, if condition **inside the loop is/are true.** i tried `labels` and `GoTo` but it will executed all time will not depend on the condition inside the loop.
i have the following code :

```
 Dim i As Integer
 For i = 1 To 50
    If i > 35 Then
    ' break the loop
    End If
 Next
```

I had tried with `GoTo` it works properly, some times it execute by default doese not depend on the condition given inside the loop

```
  If i > 35 Then
    GoTo lbl
  End If 
lbl: ' code comes here
```

Thank you......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `Exit` command for this kind of break ; `Exit Sub` is used to comes out from a particular `Sub`, `Exit Function` will help you to comes out from a function, here you can use `Exit For` hence **your code will be like the following**

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 50
If i > 35 Then
Exit For
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

```
If i > 35 Then
    Exit For
End If
```

However your code with Goto would work too - provided the `lbl:` is outside the loop.